# Return last non-empty cell conditional on value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I want to return the last non-empty cell conditional on a cell value. What I want is to return the Return column (see picture)

[image: here]

I'm able to return the last non-empty cell with this:

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/(D:D<>"");C:C)
```

However, I cannot do the same conditional on the values in range B:B.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can either use a pivot table or use `MAXIFS` for this. If you don't have `MAXIFS` then have a look [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/maximum-if-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Even `SUMIFS` would work in your case =)

Comment: No that formula isn't correct, try: `SUMIFS(C:C;D:D;"JB";B:B;F3)` in `G3`...drag down. It would even be better if you refrain from using whole column references =). And as mentioned. A pivot table would also do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, the solution should also work if there is another text in the D column. It can be everything in column D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, put the following in `G3`.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C;D:D;"<>";B:B;F3)
```

Drag down. And as mentioned, it is generally better to not use whole column references or you can just use a simple pivote table.

---

Using `MAXIFS`:

```
=MAXIFS(C:C;D:D;"<>";B:B;F3)
```

---

Alternatively:

If multiple values exists in column `D` and you don't have `MAXIFS`, then try to use `MAX` with some `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(C$3:C$11;MAX(INDEX((D$3:D$11<>"")*(B$3:B$11=F3)*ROW(A$3:A$11);))-2)
```

Drag down...

Comment: This works for the example I gave. However, I just realised my data looks different. Sometimes, there is text in cells like D3, D4 and D5, and then this formula sums the dates instead of returning the last date. Can you help me?